# checking numeric in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to show the 'valid' message if the variable value is

- not numeric with length of 10
- an empty string (`""`)

```
if(isNaN(num) && num !="" && num.length!=10)
{
    alert("invalid");
}
else
{
    alert("valid");
}
```

But this code shows 'digits which length is not 10' as valid. But whether it is numeric or not numeric, if its length is not 10 it should be invalid.

Comment: `length` is a property valid for string. What do you mean by length here? The number of digits ?

Comment: If am nt wrong you want lenth not must be greater then 10

Comment: number of characters of text box value.. whether it is numeric or alphanumeric

Comment: if you just want to check for the length of string not equal to 10, irrespective of whether it is a number or not, then you just need one check and that is num.length!=10.

Comment: @satinder singh length should not be 10 an it should not be numeric.

Comment: @chriz: ok in your case you want lengh  shud be less or greater then 10 is valid but not equal to 10

Comment: @bazz i don't want any alphabets in my string.. assume i am trying to take a mobile number.. it's length should be 10 and it should be numeric also.. so it should show valid only in this case..

Comment: to check if numeric you can see that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

Comment: @chriz: in prev above comment you  said `@satinder singh length should not be 10 an it should not be numeric` and now `@bazz i don't want any alphabets in my string.`  Pls clear you question WHAT YOU WANT ??

Comment: then your check should be  if(!Nan(num) && num.length!=10)

Comment: ok.. i know that its working alone but when i add it with length property in condition, not showing expected result..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Condtion placement is wrong here.

```
isNaN(num) && num !=""
here, for num=1234,isNaN is false(that means it is number), but the num!="" will give true resulting in Invalid alert.
```

**Solution**
replace `&&` with `||` for `OR` condtion.

Comment: REPLACE your `&& with || ` How did you miss that

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this:

```
if(is_nan(num) && num !="" && num.length<10)
{
alert("invalid");
}
else
{
alert("valid");
}
```

Otherwise if length is `<9` or `>10`, you will get **false**.

In this case you will alert `valid` when your ***num*** is non-numeric, nun-empty string with length >= 10.